# Find ASP.NET WebForms Control and change its ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms, code-behind

How can I find this checkbox on blue line below on code behind?

I've tried to use FindControl method like this:

CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl("pendencia_count");

And also tried to find on GridView, but the result is always null.

There is a loop on grid and the controls are generated with equal IDs. I need to dynamically change its IDs.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: How are you doing the loop?  If you're looping through each GridViewRow, it'll be so much easier, especially if you only have one type of Checkbox in that row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            CheckBox box = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("pendencia_count");

            if(box != null)
            {
                box.ID = "yourid" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the checkbox control into a ViewState while it is being bound, and take the checkbox control from the ViewState when you need to change its ID.

```
protected void grdPendenciasCliente_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("pendencia_count");
        ViewState["CheckBoxPendenciaCount"] = cb;
    }
}

:
if (ViewState["CheckBoxPendenciaCount"] != null)
{
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)ViewState["CheckBoxPendenciaCount"];
}
```

Comment: I had already tried it that way, but it didn't work and the object error not found unfortunately appears. It appears that there are several branches within the gridview that prevent you from locating the control.

Comment: I updated it with the solution JobesK provided, which I think should work.